# Assign integer values to color in opengl es 2.0

Tags: opengl-es-2.0, glsl, glsles

i need to set color by byte type or integer,  not float values. 
How can i assign this type into `gl_FragColor`? 
Dividing the value by 256 wont give me the wanted precision. 
My main purpose is to know the specific value of each bit in the color buffer,  if i draw line only with specific color.
for example i want that in the color buffer at the red value of pixel only 2 lsbits will be on,  what color value should i transfer to `gl_FragColor`? 
If i had an option to write byte type values,  i would write the value 3 to red component
Thanks

Comment: If you are using glVertexAttribPointer to submit your data, then set *normalized* parameter to true and supply your data as int.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, gl_FragColor must always be floating point. However, if you know the colour buffer is 8 bits per channel it shouldn't be hard to force whatever you want into it. You might consider

```
gl_FragColor = vec4(floor(number)/255.0, 0, 0, 0);
```

for example. The more recent versions of GLSL support bitwise operations, but I doubt GLES2 does.

If you want to draw to specific bits, maybe...

```
glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glBlendFunc(GL_ONE, GL_ONE);
```

...

```
gl_FragColor = vec4(pow(2.0, bitIndex)/255.0, 0, 0, 0);
```

I haven't tested this but see no reason why it couldn't work assuming geometry never overlaps (in which case the bit would overflow into the next).